# error expected expression on do while loop c++

Tags: c++

I am not done with my code yet but so far I have a error, all the way in the bottom where I am trying to do my do while statement the first line 
`cout << "Please enter one of the following: \n";` says expected expression so it is not letting me run the code, help please?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numTickets, options, count = 0;
    double total, discount, costTicket = 10, discountPrice = .05;
    char member;

    cout << ":)\t Welcome to the Regal Entertainment Group Theater\t :)\n"
         << ":)\t ****The greatest movie theater in the world.****\t :)\n\n";

    cout << "Please enter one of the following: \n";
    cout << "1 - I want tickets to watch the movie!\n"
         << "2 - I'm out.\n";

    cin >> options;

    cout << "How many tickets will you need to watch your movie tonight? ";
    cin >> numTickets;

    cout << "Are you a member of our marvelous Regal Crown Club (Y/N)? ";
    cin >> member;

    if(numTickets <= 0)
        cout << "Please enter a number greater than 0.";
    else if(numTickets < 4)
        costTicket = 10;
    else if(numTickets >= 5)
        costTicket = 8;

    if(member == 'Y' || member == 'y')
    {
        discount = costTicket * numTickets * discountPrice;

        total = numTickets * costTicket - discount;

        cout << "Your total for the movie tickets is going to be: ";
        cout << "$" << total << endl;
        cout << "You saved $" << discount << endl;

        cout << "You can pick up your free small popcorn at the stand.\n";
        cout << "Thanks for coming to watch your movie at Regal Entertainment Group!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        total = numTickets * costTicket;

        cout << "Your total for the movie tickets is going to be: ";
        cout << "$" << total << endl;
        cout << "Thanks for coming to watch your movie at Regal Entertainment Group!\n";
    }

    system("cls");

    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter one of the following: \n";
        cout << "1 - I want tickets to watch the movie!\n";
        cout << "2 - I'm out.\n";

        cin >> options;
    }while(options != 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [I can't reproduce your error.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc0323c7cf91ddff) You've done a good job with the "Complete" in [mcve], but the other two could currently use work.

Comment: I also can't reproduce your error.  I tried running it in cpp.sh, and it seems to run fine (though I don't know what you intend to accomplish).